# Converting double to hexadecimal - Code review

Tags: c++, ieee-754

I have the following code that takes a double value and converts it to a hexadecimal representation, and vice versa.  I would like to know whether there are any potential problems with it - whether I have overlooked something.

```
double hex_to_double2(string &hexString)
{
    unsigned char byte_string[sizeof(double)];
    int number;

    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < hexString.size() ; i += 2)
    {
        sscanf(&hexString[i], "%02x", &number);
        byte_string[j] = (unsigned char)number;
        ++j;
    }

    double p = (double&)byte_string;
    return p;
}

std::string double_to_hex_string(double d)
{
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)&d;
    int bufferSize = sizeof(double);

    char converted[bufferSize * 2];

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < bufferSize ; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(&converted[j*2], "%02X", buffer[i]);
        ++j;
    }
    string hex_string(converted);
    return hex_string;
}
```

It seems to work fine. But I have been told by someone that `char converted[bufferSize * 2];` should be `char converted[bufferSize * 2 + 1];`

Is this the case?

Comment: If you have a C99-compatible `printf` implementation, you can consider using the `"%a"` format string to check against your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the size of `converted` should be `bufferSize * 2 + 1`. You need room for a zero or null character at the end of the string.

`sprintf` is inserting a null character at the end of the string, but you didn't make space for it; this means it's destroying some value in memory that comes just after the buffer. It's hard to predict what side effect this might have; it might mess up the value of some other variable, it might crash your program, or it might just appear to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Each invocation of sprintf() will write three characters in your buffer: two hex digits and a null to terminate the string.  The last of these will write one beyond the buffer as currently implemented.

Answer (score 1):

One more problem with putting a `double` in a `char byte_string [sizeof(double)]` is *alignment*. This rather tricky strategy is called *type punning*. You would want to allocate `sizeof(double)*2` bytes in that function, too, and then construct an aligned pointer into the middle of the buffer.

Generally this sort of "casting about" is a bad idea, but you happen to be on the right side of the rules, almost. You just want to cast a `double` to a `char` array instead of the other way around. Also, `scanf` can do more work for you, and eliminate the loop.

```
double hex_to_double2(string &hexString)
{
    double value;

    sscanf( hexString.c_str(), "%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx",
            (char*) & value, // note, this is a reinterpret_cast
            (char*) & value + 1,
            (char*) & value + 2,
            (char*) & value + 3,
            (char*) & value + 4,
            (char*) & value + 5,
            (char*) & value + 6,
            (char*) & value + 7 );

    return p;
}
```

You are only allowed to use this sort of pointer typecast from POD types (plain old data, or C-compatible) to `char`.

I'll leave the other way around as an exercise :) .

Answer (score 1):

This is the very simple method that I am using to convert two individual doubles with a max of 255 to hex (firstNumber and secondNumber):

```
std::string hexCodes = "0123456789abcdef";

std::stringstream finalResult;

finalResult << hexCodes.at(floor(firstNumber/ 16)) << hexCodes.at(firstNumber- (16 * (floor(firstNumber/ 16))));

finalResult << hexCodes.at(floor(secondNumber/ 16)) << hexCodes.at(secondNumber- (16 * (floor(secondNumber/ 16))));

std::string finalString = finalResult.str();
```

I am not very good at writing code and after trawling google for a result to this problem I didn't find any solutions, so wrote this and it works...so far

Answer (score 0):

Yes, character arrays (also known as C strings) should usually be terminated by '\0'. This works as a length indicator in C.

```
char converted[bufferSize * 2 + 1];
converted[bufferSize*2] = '\0';
or
std::memset(converted, 0, bufferSize*2+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... any potential problems ...

`hex_to_double2` doesn't check the string fits in your `byte_string` buffer: you should either check `hexString.size()` in advance, or add an exit condition to your for loop.

You're also returning a pointer to a local buffer, which goes out of scope when `hex_to_double2` returns - don't do this. It may well deceive you by working ... until it breaks.  Maybe just return `std::vector<unsigned char>` - that would take care of the buffer lifetime *and* you could fix your for loop by using `push_back`.

> I have been told by someone that `char converted[bufferSize * 2]` should be `char converted[bufferSize * 2 + 1]`

Yes, `sprintf` appends a nul-terminator, so your output buffer should be bigger. But, since you're using `std::string` anyway, why not just format your hex digits into a `std::ostringstream`?  Again, this will fix your buffer size issues and manage the memory for you.