# Converting double rgba color values to character of hex

Tags: c++, colors, rgb, hex, rgba

I have an array of doubles with rgba color values. Something like this:

```
double* colorVals = new double[4];
colorVals[0] = 0; 
colorVals[1] = 129;
colorVals[2] = 255;
colorVals[3] = .4;
```

I want to convert it to a string with Hex that contains something like this: "#0081FF"

How would I do this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

if you know that the values are in range, you can use this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

std::string rgbstr(const double *rgb) {
  char tmp[8];

  std::snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "#%02x%02x%02x", int(rgb[0]), int(rgb[1]), int(rgb[2]));
  return std::string(tmp);
}
```

Comment: This works nice! But, shouldn't the alpha value be encoded too?

Comment: "Unlike RGB values, there is no hexadecimal notation for an RGBA value.", says the CSS3 specification, and the example in the question has only 6 digits. So I think this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert each double to hex that will be two character and then join all of them to a single string
Note: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995656/converting-double-to-hexadecimal-code-review) to see how to convert double to hex

Comment: That link is misleading. Hex notation for colors represent the RGB(A) integer values, not raw byte values of a double.